# How to wrap and scale down text at the same time in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a text inside circular container and that text is coming from an API. So I have no control over the length of the text. I show that text inside container despite of how long it is by scaling it down with FittedBox.

```
             Container(
                        height: 44,
                        width: 44,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Flexible(
                              child: FittedBox(
                                child: Text('Best Seller'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Color(0xFFF37C43)),
                      )
```

My question is how can I show all the words of the text in new line while scaling them down as well. I was thinking about using Column and generating child widgets from each word of the text. But it does not seem very intuitive. I am open to change my layout design if that is what is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Container(
        height: 44,
        width: 44,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Wrap(
          children: [
            Text('Best Seller', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),),
          ],
        ),
        decoration:
            BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Color(0xFFF37C43)),
      ),
```

Comment: It solves only half of my problem which is to wrap the text. But text still overflows container when the it gets big.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the `fontSize` compatible with the length of the word. example:

```
Text(
  myString,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: myString.length > 60? 30: myString.length > 40? 40 : 50,
  ),
)
```